# Tar up the whole BLFS system

Tags: boot, partition, grub2, lfs

I have successfully installed BLFS 8.4 and now I want to transfer it to another machine. Would it work if I tar up the whole BLFS system and then untar it on an empty partition on another machine? If this is true then what all things should I tar up. I want the whole BLFS along will all the packages in `/sources` directory.

I think I would also need 'Super Grub 2' as it scans through all the partitions and search for all the operating systems.

Please note that I don't have the host operating system. I started making LFS on Ubuntu using terminal but to give more space to the LFS, I deleted it using a disk partition tool. It means that now I have only one OS in my laptop i.e. BLFS 8.4 . I didn't use Virtual Box or any other similar software due to hardware limitations.

Comment: As I don't have any other operating system is there a way to make the tarball of the BLFS from inside the BLFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cd /
tar -cvpxf backup.tar.xz --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/dev --exclude=/proc --exclude=/backup.tar.xz /
```

This command will create a backup of the entire system in the root directory by the name `backup.tar.xz`. Be sure to exclude more directories that you would probably not need like `/tmp`.